# Can i import some custom module after a angular 2 app bootstraped?

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular-bootstrap

I am developing a business web app using **angular2** based on web api.
Now i got a problem. I want to bootstrap my angular2 app using AuthModule(this is my custom module). This module have functionalty to perform login and signup operation. I don't want to bootstrap my full angular2 app when a user not logged in. I want to import all modules and components After a user successfully logged in. Just like that..

In main.ts

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

after login success,

```
// i need to import my modules after login
//platform.importModule([MyCustomModule]);.....
```

I don't know this is possible or not.
I don't see any API documentation in [angular.io](http://angular.io) site.
Please give me any idea if this is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: You should make some research about "lazy load module angular2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you are using platform.importModule for loading your customModule. you can use lazy loading of angular 2 for this.

here are some useful links:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html in this see how they have used lazy loading.

study from these links how to use lazy loading.